# Relation: add button to create node related to current node

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

I have 2 Content types called **Schools** and **School News** and i want to add a **add News** Button to those School pages, so editors can create a new post for this specific school. I thought about using relation module as i am using it already for other things.

Would it be possible to create such a button that adds a hidden field with the ID of the specific school into the news form? That way i could add this relation while saving the node. Is there any other way to get this kind of functionality with relation?

Answer (score 2):

The [Node Reference URL](https://drupal.org/project/nodereference_url) module works with the [References](https://drupal.org/project/references) module to accomplish this feature. When you add a node reference field, you can specify `Reference From URL` widget which will auto fill the field from a value in the URL. You can also specify (in the field settings) to display a link on the referenceable node.

In your case, you would create a node reference field on **School News** that references **Shools**. Just select the `Reference From URL` widget and configure as necessary.

There's an older lullabot [video about creating image galleries](http://www.lullabot.com/articles/photo-galleries-views-attach) in Drupal 6 that demonstrates how it works. The Drupal 7 version has the same features and works the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this help you: [Relation autoconnect](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/bobik/1256164)